# SF short story from 1960-1980 about the murder of a Martian who played a form of golf using a jewelled boomerang

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, soft-sci-fi, mars

I think this short story was in one of the “Gold” collection series.

It was about the murder of a Martian who played a form of golf using a jewelled boomerang. The human eventually convicted ends up in an execution chamber designed to execute Martians, who have a hard carapace.

It would have been a contemporary of such favourites as “Watchbird” and “Horror Howse” (yup, that’s how it was spelled, as I recall). I’m looking for the title, author and collection title.

Comment: What is the "Gold" collection? The only one I know is the [Asimov anthology of that name](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?198665). Do you mean one of the anthologies edited by H. L. Gold?

Comment: "Watchbird" is presumably [the Sheckley story](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46236), but what is "Horror Howse"?

Comment: Perhaps ["Horrer Howce" (1956)](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45915), by Margaret St. Clair.

Comment: Aha, yes, and indeed that has been collect in H. L. Gold's _Galaxy Reader_ series.

Comment: https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v12n03_1956-07/page/n105/mode/2up for a copy FWIW

Answer (score 12):

Are you sure it was Mars and not Venus?

Otherwise it sounds very like Fred Pohl's "[The Gentlest Unpeople](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?63139)". The central character, an explorer from Earth iirc, has accidentally killed a Venusian in the middle of a "whirlarang" contest. The Venusians accept that the killing was accidental, but he has nonetheless incurred the death penalty by interrupting the game.

Executions are performed by a robot which apparently just tears the offender to pieces. As a kindness, he is led to believe that he is being reprieved, but then taken into a room where the Justice Machine awaits him.

The story was indeed included in *The Fourth Galaxy Reader*, edited by Gold.

Comment: Just read it in *Tomorrow Times Seven*! That's gotta be it, nice job.

Comment: And "Horror Howce" is also in the 4th Galaxy Reader.